# Restrict product using date in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I need to restrict the list of product with respect to date .

For example  I need to display products created between 1.1.2015 to 1.1.2016

Here is my code

```
   $products=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
  //$products->addAttributeToSelect('name');
   $products->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail', 'price','description','special_price')); 

 foreach ($products as $product) {
$p['products'][] = array(
            'id'        => $product->getId(),
            'sku'       => $product->getSku(),
            'name'      => $product->getName(),
            'thumb'     => (string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail'),
        'description'   => $product->getDescription(),
          'weight'      => $product->getWeight(),
        'created at'    => $product->getCreatedAt(),
            'pirce'     => Mage::helper('core')->currency($product->getPrice(), true, false), //." ".$currencyCode,
        'Special pirce' => Mage::helper('core')->currency($product->getFinalPrice(), true, false) 



        );
}

var_dump($result);
```

Please suggest me with a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $products=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
  //$products->addAttributeToSelect('name');
   $products->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail','price','description','special_price')); 

 $first = date('m/j/Y', strtotime('2015-01-01'));    
 $last =  date('m/j/Y', strtotime('2016-01-01'));

//--please add these filters
  $products->addAttributeToFilter('created at', array('gteq' =>$first));
  $products->addAttributeToFilter('created at', array('lteq' => $last));

 foreach ($products as $product) {
$p['products'][] = array(
            'id'        => $product->getId(),
            'sku'       => $product->getSku(),
            'name'      => $product->getName(),
            'thumb'     => (string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init(
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816

Comment: why this comes :--Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php

Comment: I have used created at instead of created_at

Answer (score 0):

Please, use usually filters of magento-collection.
https://gyazo.com/7d4b90d626b09c4a4fafd69c9f540e9d